# mariadb not recognizing localhost user

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I recently upgraded from MySQL to MariaDB 10.1.36 as part of an XAMPP upgrade, where I had a user account associated with performing some basic backup tasks.  I noticed that for the last few days, this task has not run, so I went to check it out and I discovered this:

```
"Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database...
```

The command I'm running is:

```
mysqldump -u asdf test test_db > d:\\backup\\mysql_backup.sql
```

This has worked for years on MySQL - but once I upgraded it seems that user `asdf` no longer has access to run this on localhost.

Using phpmyadmin, I've granted all privileges to this user.  If I change the script to call the root user instead `mysqldump -u root test test_db...` it works, but I would rather not have to change all my scripts to use root instead of the asdf user I specifically set up for this.

How do I grant access for user `asdf` to run things on localhost?

Comment: `CREATE USER 'asdf'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED VIA mysql_native_password USING '***';GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'asdf'@'localhost' REQUIRE NONE WITH GRANT OPTION`

Comment: Security is getting tighter.